# How do I install vlc-srpos-plugin on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to install [vlc-srpos-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/vlc-srpos-plugin/) (a VLC plugin that remembers your video position) on Ubuntu.

I've downloaded and extracted **libsrpos_plugin-*.tar.gz** (for Linux or Unix systems)

The [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/vlc-srpos-plugin/#Installation) say:

> Unix/Linux and similar systems: Build and install plugin module (Use
>   configure options to specify VLC include/library/output paths
>   (--with-vlc-*-path options)):
>
> ```
>  ./configure  
>  make  
>  make install
> ```

When I run `./configure` without options I get `configure: error: VLC plugin headers not found`, but I can't work out what --with-vlc-*-path option values to use.

The relevant options seem to have these names:

```
$ grep "\-\-with\-vlc\-" configure
  --with-vlc-include-path location of the VLC SDK headers, defaults to
  --with-vlc-lib-path     location of the vlccore library
  --with-vlc-plugin-path  location of the VLC plugin modules, defaults to
```

but what values should I use for Ubuntu 12.04?

Extra info:

```
$ whereis vlc
vlc: /usr/bin/vlc /etc/vlc /usr/lib/vlc /usr/bin/X11/vlc /usr/share/vlc /usr/share/man/man1/vlc.1.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Asked the same question on the VLC forum and [got this answer](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=108346&p=367259#p367259):

> install **`libvlc-dev`** if you want to compile a VLC plugin yourself on Debian or Ubuntu

Doing this enables configure to work first time, without any options.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Tom: You should accept your answer if it worked for you.