# How to install vlc-srpod-plugin?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, plugins

I'm trying to install vlc-srpos-plugin (a VLC plugin that remembers your video position) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've downloaded and extracted libsrpos_plugin-*.tar.gz (for Linux or Unix systems)

The instructions say:

> - Unix/Linux and similar systems:
>     Build and install plugin module:
>       ./configure
>       make
>       make install
>     Use configure options to specify VLC include/library/output paths
>     (--with-vlc-*-path options).

When I run `./configure` without options I get configure: `error: VLC plugin headers not found`, but I can't work out what `--with-vlc-*-path` option values to use.

The relevant options seem to have these names:

`$ grep "\-\-with\-vlc\-" configure`

> --with-vlc-include-path location of the VLC SDK headers, defaults to
>                           /usr/include/vlc/plugins
>   --with-vlc-lib-path     location of the vlccore library
>   --with-vlc-plugin-path  location of the VLC plugin modules, defaults to
>                           /usr/include/vlc/plugins
>   # Check whether --with-vlc-include-path was given.
>   # Check whether --with-vlc-lib-path was given.
>   # Check whether --with-vlc-plugin-path was given.

but what values should I use for Ubuntu 14.04 and VLC 2.1.4?

## Extra info:

```
$ whereis vlc
vlc: /usr/bin/vlc /usr/lib/vlc /usr/bin/X11/vlc /usr/include/vlc /usr/share/vlc /usr/share/man/man1/vlc.1.gz
```

I installed **`libvlc-dev`** due to instructions found in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/549288/how-do-i-install-vlc-srpos-plugin-on-ubuntu) and [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=108346&p=367259#p367259), but the problem exist yet!

Answer (score 1):

Install **`libvlccore-dev`** using your package manager or `sudo apt-get install libvlccore-dev`. This will solve the problem with `./configure`